# How to determine rows or records that is present in some n previous months in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

i have a table, that contains info about the when did the user start and end a particular task. i have a situation where in i need to find whether the task is created in last month and closed in this month

for eg: a Task "A" is created on 01-Sep-2020 and same task is closed on 17th-Jan-2021. i need to find this record and display sum of hours worked in all the months based on date range selected (like '01-Sep-2020' to '31-Jan-2021')

there is a table to store all task details. below is a sample data

| Task Name | Start Date Time | End Date Time | Allocated Minutes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Task A | 2020-11-30 11:00:00.000 | 2020-12-01 11:00:00.000 | 1440 |
| Task B | 2020-12-02 11:00:00.000 | 2020-12-03 11:00:00.000 | 1440 |
| Task C | 2020-31-01 11:00:00.000 | 2021-01-01 11:00:00.000 | 1440 |

please help me in this regard. any help would be appreciated.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: please show some sample data, expected result and the attempted query

Comment: hi check this link https://www.encodedna.com/sqlserver/tips/how-to-get-previous-months-records-in-sql-server.htm

Comment: @RaviKumar sir, i need to find records which is created in any of the previous month's and closed in current month based on date range selected

Comment: What is the issue you are facing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the date range you want with `eomonth` and `dateadd` in sql-server

```
select * 
from [tablename]
where startdate between dateadd(day,1,eomonth(dateadd(month,-2,getdate()))) and eomonth(dateadd(month,-1,getdate()))
and enddate between dateadd(day,1,eomonth(dateadd(month,-1,getdate()))) and eomonth(getdate())
```

this will fetch the row which startdate in last month and enddate in this month.

Answer (score 0):

You can find data between two dates like this:

```
declare @startDate varchar(20)
declare @endDate varchar(20)
set @startDate = '01/01/2021'
set @endDate = '01/01/2020'

select Task_Name from YOUR_TABLE
where date >= @startDate 
and   date < @endDate
```

and find hours between two dates:

```
select 
    CONVERT(int,DATEDIFF(hh, @endDate , @startDate ) / 60) as Hrs_Difference
```

Answer (score 0):

> whether the task is created in last month and closed in this month

I would use `datefromparts()`:

```
where startdatetime < datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1) and
      startdatetime >= dateadd(month, -1, datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1) and          
      enddatetime >= datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1)
```

This assumes you have no future enddatetimes, which seems quite reasonable.